# Multiplying the list of numbers without multiply

Tags: list, python-2.7, multiplication, addition

I am trying to multiply the elements in the list so that they give me their total but with only using addition and subtraction. For example, a list of [1,3,6,8] will have the output 144. The code I have so far is:

```
numbers = [1,3,6,8]
def no_sign(numbers):
    total = 0
    answer = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):

        first_number = numbers[i]
        print str(first_number) + ' pop'
        for j in range(first_number):
            #print first_number
            answer = first_number + answer
            print str(first_number) + ' firstnum'
            print str(answer)+ " answeer "

        total = total + answer
        print str(total) + " total"

    return total
```

print no_sign(numbers)

This only gives me 110, which isn't enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the first thing I notice is that your `for j in range(...):` loop is basically squaring each number, rather than multiplying any of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Your code takes the square of each element and adds them up. Hence you are getting `1 + 9 + 36 + 64 = 110`

Since you want to do same thing couple times, writing your `multiplication(num1, num2)` function yourself with only addition and using that when multiplying would be much better choice.

Multiplication of two numbers, as you know, is adding firstNumber to itself secondNumber of times. S you can write `multiplication` function like below and use it on a list.

```
def multiplication(num1, num2): 
    answer = 0
    for i in range(num2):
        answer += num1       
    return answer

numbers = [1,3,6,8]
def no_sign(numbers):
    total = 1 
    for number in numbers:
        total = multiplication(total, number)    
    return total

print no_sign(numbers)
```